# I'm trying to set build name based on package.json file in jenkins but I just got an error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to set in my build name the version of the package.json file. I have my environment with the plugins "Build Name and Description Setter 2.2.0" and "token macro 293.v283932a_0a_b_49" when I ran my pipeline jobs I got the following error:

Failed to evaluate name macro:org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.MacroEvaluationException: Error processing tokens

This is my Build Name in the job: SQ_${JSON, file="./package.json", path="version"}

Comment: Can you add more  info, like is it a pipeline job? if yes, share the jenkinsfile/syntax used to set build name.

Comment: Hi Parvez, yes it's a pipeline job. The syntax I used was SQ_${JSON, file="./package.json", path="version"}

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like -

```
def package = readJSON file: 'package.json'
def version = package.version
currentBuild.displayName = "${BUILD_NUMBER} - ${version}"
```

Ref - https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace

Comment: Seems like def package is reserved, I used def npmPackage instead. Might be of help for someone else.